# Adding a rich text editor to Excerpt

Tags: editor, excerpt

I need add to the excerpt field the TinyMCE Advanced editor, any ideas?

I have the qTranslate plugin (multilanguage), and it's impossible to connect teh excerpt with this plugin and an editor.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just replace the default output. Make sure you unescape the excerpt before you send it to the editor:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array ( 'T5_Richtext_Excerpt', 'switch_boxes' ) );

/**
 * Replaces the default excerpt editor with TinyMCE.
 */
class T5_Richtext_Excerpt
{
    /**
     * Replaces the meta boxes.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function switch_boxes()
    {
        if ( ! post_type_supports( $GLOBALS['post']->post_type, 'excerpt' ) )
        {
            return;
        }

        remove_meta_box(
            'postexcerpt' // ID
        ,   ''            // Screen, empty to support all post types
        ,   'normal'      // Context
        );

        add_meta_box(
            'postexcerpt2'     // Reusing just 'postexcerpt' doesn't work.
        ,   __( 'Excerpt' )    // Title
        ,   array ( __CLASS__, 'show' ) // Display function
        ,   null              // Screen, we use all screens with meta boxes.
        ,   'normal'          // Context
        ,   'core'            // Priority
        );
    }

    /**
     * Output for the meta box.
     *
     * @param  object $post
     * @return void
     */
    public static function show( $post )
    {
    ?>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="excerpt"><?php
        _e( 'Excerpt' )
        ?></label>
        <?php
        // We use the default name, 'excerpt', so we don’t have to care about
        // saving, other filters etc.
        wp_editor(
            self::unescape( $post->post_excerpt ),
            'excerpt',
            array (
            'textarea_rows' => 15
        ,   'media_buttons' => FALSE
        ,   'teeny'         => TRUE
        ,   'tinymce'       => TRUE
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * The excerpt is escaped usually. This breaks the HTML editor.
     *
     * @param  string $str
     * @return string
     */
    public static function unescape( $str )
    {
        return str_replace(
            array ( '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&amp;', '&nbsp;', '&amp;nbsp;' )
        ,   array ( '<',    '>',    '"',      '&',     ' ', ' ' )
        ,   $str
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Save this code in a plugin or in your theme’s `functions.php`.

Comment: Thanks, still works out of the box in 2018 for WP 4.9.x :)

Comment: Works perfectly in 5.1 version (Feb 2019), thanks!

Comment: Still works in 2020, even post-Gutenberg (though I only tested it with "Classic Editor" plugin enabled)

Comment: Still working in 5.8.1 (Sept 2021). I wonder how to add the Add Media button too.

Comment: I've found that this snippet seems to conflict with WooCommerce as it makes it impossible to update the "Product Short Description". The edits simply doesn't save.  Took me a while to figure this out so I'd like to warn others.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to use the plugin [Rich Text Excerpt](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-text-excerpts/)

The Plugin uses the [wp_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) function to generate a rich text editor for page/post excerpts, so will only work in WordPress 3.3 or greater.

Comment: I try it, but it's incompatible with qTranslate plugin, any idea to make it work?

Comment: I will look into it.

Comment: Any idea why excerpt is not a rich text box by default?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use `wp_editor` function to get rich editor, then you should remove any sanitize functions with `get_post_meta` (or `update_post_meta`), then you should use `htmlspecialchars_decode` function to get the rich content..

## look through this principle:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'adding_a_new_metaabox' );                
function adding_a_new_metaabox() 
    {   
        add_meta_box('html_myid_31_section', 'TITLE Hellooo', 'my_output_funct');
    }

function my_output_funct( $post ) 
    {
    //so, dont ned to use esc_attr in front of get_post_meta
    $valueeee2=  get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'SMTH_METANAME' , true ) ;
    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($valueeee2), 'mettaabox_ID_stylee', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'MyInputNAMEE') );
    }


function save_my_post_data( $post_id ) 
{                   
    if (!empty($_POST['MyInputNAMEE']))
        {
        $datta=htmlspecialchars($_POST['MyInputNAMEE']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'SMTH_METANAME', $datta );
        }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_my_post_data' );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Follow solution add excerpt wysiwyg editor right after post title.

[image: Excerpt]

Add follow class to your Wordpress project as `excerpt.php`

```
class Excerpt {

    public function __construct() {
        add_filter('excerpt_more', [$this, 'excerpt_more']);
        add_action('edit_form_after_title', [$this, 'excerpt']);
        add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'remove_excerpt_metabox']);
        add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', [$this, 'wp_trim_excerpt'], 10, 2);
    }

    /**
     * Remove metabox from post
     */
    public function remove_excerpt_metabox() {
        remove_meta_box('postexcerpt', 'post', 'normal');
    }

    /**
     * Strip tags
     *
     * @param string $text
     * @return string
     */
    public function wp_trim_excerpt($text = '') {
        return strip_tags($text, '<a><strong><em><b><i><code><ul><ol><li><blockquote><del><ins><img><pre><code><>');
    }

    /**
     * More sign...
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function excerpt_more() {
        return '&hellip;';
    }

    /**
     * Excerpt editor after post title.
     *
     * @param $post
     */
    public function excerpt($post) {
        if ($post->post_type !== 'post') return;
        wp_editor(
            html_entity_decode($post->post_excerpt),
            'html-excerpt',
            [
                'teeny' => true,
                'quicktags' => true,
                'wpautop' => true,
                'media_buttons' => false,
                'textarea_rows' => 7,
                'textarea_name' => 'excerpt'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Then add to `functions.php` file follow lines:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/excerpt.php';
$excerpt = new Excerpt();
```

Comment: doesn't seem tow ork