# Allow HTML in excerpt

Tags: php, excerpt

Here is my excerpt code.

```
// Generate custom excerpt length
function wpbx_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 300;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'wpbx_excerpt_length');
```

How do I allow html like `<a> <b> <i> <br>`

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**COMPLETE GUIDE TO EXCERPTS**

I've recently answered a few questions regarding excerpts, so I'm going to give a detailed explanation covering as much as I can.

**PREFACE**

There seems to be a couple of questions arising from this answer on where the code should go, and the answer is, it is really up to you and how you see fit. There are are a couple of options where you can place the code (if not explicitly stated):

- In your theme's functions.php or any file use as a functions file. Just remember when you do this, if the theme is not your own, all changes will be lost when you upgrade your theme
- A better way would be to use the code in a child theme. As above, in the functions.php or functions related file
- Use the code in a plugin. This is the prefered way as this makes the code available across all themes. If you switch themes, you don't have to worry about rewriting the same code.

I hope this clears things up a bit :-)

**HTML TAGS/FORMATTING**

[`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) first of all doesn't accept any parameters, so nothing can be passed to it. It is a fact that `the_excerpt()` trims the content to 55 words, and all HTML tags are stripped before returning the text. `the_excerpt()` is located in [wp-includes/post-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0). To allow certain or all HTML tags in the excerpt, a new excerpt has to be created.

First of all, the original function needs to be removed first, and then the new function needs to be hooked to [`get_the_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt). Please take note, this new excerpt will still be callable as `the_excerpt()` in template files, no need to change that. `get_the_excerpt()` is located in [wp-includes/post-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0).

The excerpt uses [`wp_trim_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt) to return the trimmed text, so we need to remove `wp_trim_excerpt` first from the excerpt filter. `wp_trim_excerpt()` is located in [wp-includes/formatting.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L0), line 2355. This is how:

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
```

You can now add your new excerpt to `get_the_excerpt`

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

To allow html tags/formatting, we will need to specify which tags you will need to allow. You can use the following `strip_tags` statement to achieve that

```
$wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags());
```

The second argument `wpse_allowedtags()` is a small function that is used to add the tags `the_excerpt()` will allow. For a complete list of valid HTML 5 tags, go and check it out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/). Here is function, add any html tags to this that you need to allow/keep

```
function wpse_allowedtags() {
// Add custom tags to this string
    return '<script>,<style>,<br>,<em>,<i>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<a>,<p>,<img>,<video>,<audio>'; 
}
```

If you need to allow all HTML tags, that is, no stripping of any tags, the `strips_tags()` function can be omitted/removed completely.

A point to note however, when html tags are allowed, these tags are counted as words, so your word count for excerpts with tags and without tags will not be the same. To correct that, you will need to remove these tags from the actual word count first so that only words are counted.

I have written an excerpt that will allow all tags, count only words as words, and complete a sentence after the set amount of words (so the text won't be trimmed mid-sentence) and add a read more text after the last word.

Here is the complete code

```
function wpse_allowedtags()
{
  // Add custom tags to this string
  return '<script>,<style>,<br>,<em>,<i>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<a>,<p>,<img>,<video>,<audio>';
}

if (!function_exists('wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt')) :

  function wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($wpse_excerpt)
  {
    $raw_excerpt = $wpse_excerpt;
    if ('' == $wpse_excerpt) {

      $wpse_excerpt = get_the_content('');
      $wpse_excerpt = strip_shortcodes($wpse_excerpt);
      $wpse_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $wpse_excerpt);
      $wpse_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $wpse_excerpt);
      $wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags()); /*IF you need to allow just certain tags. Delete if all tags are allowed */

      //Set the excerpt word count and only break after sentence is complete.
      $excerpt_word_count = 75;
      $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count);
      $tokens = array();
      $excerptOutput = '';
      $count = 0;

      // Divide the string into tokens; HTML tags, or words, followed by any whitespace
      preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>|[^<>\s]+)\s*/u', $wpse_excerpt, $tokens);

      foreach ($tokens[0] as $token) {

        if ($count >= $excerpt_length && preg_match('/[\,\;\?\.\!]\s*$/uS', $token)) {
          // Limit reached, continue until , ; ? . or ! occur at the end
          $excerptOutput .= trim($token);
          break;
        }

        // Add words to complete sentence
        $count++;

        // Append what's left of the token
        $excerptOutput .= $token;
      }

      $wpse_excerpt = trim(force_balance_tags($excerptOutput));

      $excerpt_end = ' <a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__('Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'wpse'), get_the_title()) . '</a>';
      $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);

      //$pos = strrpos($wpse_excerpt, '</');
      //if ($pos !== false)
      // Inside last HTML tag
      //$wpse_excerpt = substr_replace($wpse_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0); /* Add read more next to last word */
      //else
      // After the content
      $wpse_excerpt .= $excerpt_more; /*Add read more in new paragraph */

      return $wpse_excerpt;

    }
    return apply_filters('wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $wpse_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
  }

endif;

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

You can just remove the '//' from functions that you need extra.

**CUSTOM EXCERPT LENGTHS**

Sometimes you need to display simple excerpts of different lengths and it is not viable to write an excerpt for every post/function/page. Here is a nice small little function using `wp_trim_words`

```
function wpse_custom_excerpts($limit) {
    return wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), $limit, '<a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&hellip;' . __( 'Read more &nbsp;&raquo;', 'wpse' ) . '</a>');
}
```

What this little function does is taking `get_the_excerpt`, trimming it to `$limit` set by the user, and returning the text with a read more link at the end.

You can call this excerpt as follow in your template

```
echo wpse_custom_excerpts($limit);
```

where `$limit` will be your word count, so an excerpt of 30 words will be

```
echo wpse_custom_excerpts(30);
```

Just one thing to remember here, if you set your limit to more that 55 words, only 55 words will be returned as the excerpt is only 55 words in length. If longer excerpts are needed, use `get_the_content` instead.

**CUSTOM EXCERPT LENGTH**

If you just need to alter the length of `the_excerpt()`, you can use the following function

```
function wpse_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpse_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Remember, you will need to set a priority bigger than 10 so that your custom function executes after the default.

**ADD READ MORE LINK**

All text returned by the excerpt have the hated `[...]` at the end that is not clickable. To add a read more text in the place of the hellips, use this function

```
 function wpse_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('Read More', 'your-text-domain') . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpse_excerpt_more' );
```

**EDIT**

**Excerpt first paragraph**

I want to keep this complete, so here is the excerpt that trims after the first paragraph.

Here is a function that keeps HTML tags in tact, adds a "Read More" link at the end of the excerpt and trims the excerpt after the first paragraph.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) ) : 
    
    function wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($wpse0001_excerpt) {
        global $post;
        $raw_excerpt = $wpse0001_excerpt;
        if ( '' == $wpse0001_excerpt ) {
    
            $wpse0001_excerpt = get_the_content('');
            $wpse0001_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $wpse0001_excerpt );
            $wpse0001_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $wpse0001_excerpt);
            $wpse0001_excerpt = substr( $wpse0001_excerpt, 0, strpos( $wpse0001_excerpt, '</p>' ) + 4 );
            $wpse0001_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $wpse0001_excerpt);
    
            $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
            $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 
    
            //$pos = strrpos($wpse0001_excerpt, '</');
            //if ($pos !== false)
            // Inside last HTML tag
            //$wpse0001_excerpt = substr_replace($wpse0001_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0);
            //else
            // After the content
            $wpse0001_excerpt .= $excerpt_more;
    
            return $wpse0001_excerpt;
    
        }
        return apply_filters('wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $wpse0001_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
    }
    
endif; 
    
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

### EDIT 29-10-2015

For anyone that need a workaround to not display the read more link after the excerpt when the excerpt is shorter that the amount of words set, please see the following question and answer

- [Read more tag shows up on EVERY post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/207050/31545)

Comment: where exactly do i place this part `function wpse_allowedtags() {
// Add custom tags to this string
    return '<script>,<style>,<br>,<em>,<i>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<a>,<p>,<img>,<video>,<audio>'; 
}` im confused

Comment: All this code goes in `functions.php`. You can add that just above `if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) ) :` in your `functions.php`

Comment: @user32447 see edit

Comment: i know that but there are certain tags I want allowed and I don't know how to achieve that, i placed the code in my functions.php but what do i change to allow certain tags @pieter goosen

Comment: am i suppose to erase this line and replace it `$wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags());`

Comment: nvm i missed the top of the code

Comment: No, keep `$wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags());`. You must add your tags to these `return '<script>,<style>,<br>,<em>,<i>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<a>,<p>,<img>,<video>,<audio>';` You can also delete all this tags and just add yours

Comment: if this goes into functions.php file won't that get overwritten when an update comes along ?

Comment: @mcgrailm yes it would. That is why it is important to add this to your **child themes'** functions.php. You can even add it to a must-use plugin

Comment: Perhaps also add ":" as a token?

Comment: @PieterGoosen Wow, this is a great explanation! There is just one thing: the function is going to add words until the next . or ! (e.g.), but what if there is no more words after the final . or !? The "Read more" link is still going to show... I know the excerpt function is not supposed to show the full content but that can be hard to control if one editor write a small article. What do you think of this situation?

Comment: @Pipo You are correct. I will look at this issue after the weekend, I'm going to be a bit busy. Will keep you up to date. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @PieterGoosen No worries, there is no rush, I am just trying to learn from your code. Have a good sunday

Comment: Does this make sure that no tags are left open? I'm asking because of this [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/196105/22534).

Comment: There is an issue with ul an li tags that I am aware of, but generally, this should just actually be stripped from an excerpt. @ialocin

Comment: Nice! So if I have lets say 100 words and there is a opening tag without a closing one it will be stripped.

Comment: @ialocin no it won't. You can implement something like this to strip out tags that are left open. What I meant is, one should actually strip tags like ul and li tags from the excerpt. In one of the functions above you can do it.

Comment: Too bad, I misunderstood you then - obviously. This was more about for example the `<b>` tag.

Comment: I think this need testing :-). When I constructed this, it was more meant for a tags, which at that stage was my main issue. I only later noticed that ul and li tags got stripped halfway through, so you would sit with the opening tag and not the closing one. To be honest, this code does have it flaws :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Just mentioning that hooking the excerpt_more function won't work unless you give it a lower priority since template-tags.php is being loaded after the current theme's functions.php

Comment: @PieterGoosen thank you for the highly informative post- quick question: would it be possible to modify the excerpt in this way for only a specific post type?

Comment: Can you just write a quick solution that I can copy and paste in my code? It's summer and I don't want to read a book.

Comment: People who are wondering what to copy, there is a "Here is the complete code" section in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add more tags if you need into `$allowed_tags = ...`

```
function _20170529_excerpt($text) {
$raw_excerpt = $text;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    //Retrieve the post content. 
    $text = get_the_content('');

    //Delete all shortcode tags from the content. 
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

    $allowed_tags = '<a>,<b>,<br><i>'; 
    $text = strip_tags($text, $allowed_tags);

    $excerpt_word_count = 55; /*** MODIFY THIS. change the excerpt word count to any integer you like.***/
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 

    $excerpt_end = '[...]'; /*** MODIFY THIS. change the excerpt endind to something else.***/
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);

    $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
        array_pop($words);
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
        $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
    } else {
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
    }
}
return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
```

From :http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-preserve-html-tags-in-wordpress-excerpt-without-a-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

You can add rich text editor for excerpts as well, add below code in plugin file or theme's function.php file and you'll be able to see HTML editor for excerpts. Moreover, it'll render excerpts in HTML format as well. #cheers

I've copied this from somewhere but don't remember the source. I'm using this in my all projects and it's working.

Edit: This was copied from [Adding a rich text editor to Excerpt](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58261/adding-a-rich-text-editor-to-excerpt) 2012 answer by fuxia

[image]

```
/**
  * Replaces the default excerpt editor with TinyMCE.
*/
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array ( 'T5_Richtext_Excerpt', 'switch_boxes' ) );
class T5_Richtext_Excerpt
{
    /**
     * Replaces the meta boxes.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function switch_boxes()
    {
        if ( ! post_type_supports( $GLOBALS['post']->post_type, 'excerpt' ) )
        {
            return;
        }

        remove_meta_box(
            'postexcerpt', // ID
            '',            // Screen, empty to support all post types
            'normal'      // Context
        );

        add_meta_box(
            'postexcerpt2',     // Reusing just 'postexcerpt' doesn't work.
            __( 'Excerpt' ),    // Title
            array ( __CLASS__, 'show' ), // Display function
            null,              // Screen, we use all screens with meta boxes.
            'normal',          // Context
            'core',            // Priority
        );
    }

    /**
     * Output for the meta box.
     *
     * @param  object $post
     * @return void
     */
    public static function show( $post )
    {
        ?>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="excerpt"><?php
        _e( 'Excerpt' )
        ?></label>
        <?php
            // We use the default name, 'excerpt', so we don’t have to care about
            // saving, other filters etc.
            wp_editor(
                self::unescape( $post->post_excerpt ),
                'excerpt',
                array (
                    'textarea_rows' => 15,
                    'media_buttons' => FALSE,
                    'teeny'         => TRUE,
                    'tinymce'       => TRUE
                )
            );
    }

    /**
     * The excerpt is escaped usually. This breaks the HTML editor.
     *
     * @param  string $str
     * @return string
     */
    public static function unescape( $str )
    {
        return str_replace(
            array ( '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&amp;', '&nbsp;', '&amp;nbsp;' ),
                array ( '<',    '>',    '"',      '&',     ' ', ' ' ),
                $str
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @peter-wooster for the edit.