# Wordpress function/template tag to get first n words of the content

Tags: functions, content, template-tags

Is there a built-in function or template tag to get the first `n` words of the content? I mean `the_content()`.

Comment: You are looking for the excerpt. I done a complete answer on that. Have a look [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141136/31545)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, [`wp_trim_words()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words):

```
 <?php $trimmed = wp_trim_words( $text, $num_words = 55, $more = null ); ?>
```

Or in your case:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( strip_tags( $post->post_content ), 55 ) ); ?>
```

Comment: @JaromírtheGreenhorn If you'd like to use this on `get_the_content()`, you'll need to strip HTML beforehand (see revision).

Comment: It seems to work for me without extra strip down, but good to know.

Comment: I would still strongly advise that you use it - it might be working now, but eventually you'll end up with malformed HTML.

Comment: (*ironic*) Alright, Master, I promise to be obedient!