# Open everything in new tab

Tags: categories, tabs

I have a blog and there in category section I have a list of categories like story,poem etc. Now in the list of stories, I want that when someone clicks on continue reading, it should open the post in a new tab. How can I do it by default so that I don't have to do it for each post?

Comment: You are talking about `the_excerpt()` I assume. I did a complete answer on nearly everything about `the_excerpt()`. Check it out [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141136/31545)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are talking about `the_excerpt`. Following code will work, as you are looking for it:

```
function custom_excerpt($more) {
   global $post;
   return '<a class="moretag" target="_blank" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Continue reading...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt');
```

You will need to put it in your `functions.php` file.