# Show category post with excerpt text

Tags: posts, categories, excerpt

I want to show a post with post title and post content of 400/550 words with a read more link in my category page. I have already done this, but problem is, my post doesn't display the excerpt as it should.

This in my code below.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="news">
<div class="grid-container">

  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a><span class="line"></span></h2>

  <?php  the_post_thumbnail() ?>
  </a>
  <div class="newsevent"><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,400); ?></div>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore">View</a> </div>
<?php endwhile; 


?>
```

I suspect I need to change `<?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,400); ?>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow html in excerpt](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt)

Comment: Nearly everything you want to know about the excerpt is covered in above link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Follow this post on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260928/how-to-include-html-tags-within-a-wordpress-excerpt) or the link given by @PieterGoosen.

2) You can also use `get_the_content()` instead of `get_the_excerpt()`