# Modify Twenty Fourteen Home Page Content Limit & Add Read More Link

Tags: excerpt, theme-twenty-fourteen

I've install the new Twenty Fourteen theme for WordPress. I don't know how add summary text of posts on my front page.

All old tutorials like [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) does not work with new theme.

Any suggestions on how to solve this

Comment: thanks all for try to help but unfortunately all this solutions not work, i found this plugin who fix all my problems,

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-custom-auto-excerpt/

Comment: I've added a solution in this link, hope it helps to you.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Talk:Customizing_the_Read_More#Adding_MORE_to_all_posts_content

Comment: No, you didn't fix the problems with the plugin. It simply ignores it.

Comment: @WimVincken you posted a comment as an answer, don't do that. I've moved it here as I couldn't see what it was responding to, this question and its answers don't mention plugins, I don't know what you're referring to

Answer (score 1):

The twentyfourteen index page calls

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

inside the loop. So the content of the loop resides in template files with the name content-{$post_format}.php. All posts that does not have a post format uses content.php to display the post data

If you look at content.php, these lines are where the content is retrieved and displayed

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
                'after'       => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

By default, full post content are shown on all pages, except on the search page. To display excerpts on the home page as well, you will need to modify this section of code. All you need to do is to tell wordpress that when you are on the homepage (conditional tag [`is_home`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)), show excerpts instead of full content.

Simply change this line

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
```

to

```
<?php if ( is_search() || is_home() ) : ?>
```

**EDIT**

Remember to make this changes in a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). Never make changes to the theme itself

**EDIT 2**

If you are using a static front page, you should use `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()`. Go and check out how to make use of [**Conditional Tags**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). You should then try

```
<?php if ( is_search() || is_front_page() ) : ?>
```

For info on excerpts, go and check out my (almost complete) [**post on excerpts**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141136/31545)

Comment: @goose Don't you need to do this for every post format file?

Comment: Hahaha, no Brad. It will break your shortcodes and html tags, which in turn will break your images, videos and audio files. That is why the post format templates only display full content, not excerpts. This is what your code will do unfortunately

Comment: the_excerpt also strips out HTML & shortcodes

Comment: i need in content.php change: <?php if ( is_search() ) : ?> to <?php if ( is_search() || is_home() ) : ?> ? i do this but not work again is full text on front page ?

Comment: In my theme folder, in content.php i need change this:

<?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>

to

<?php if ( is_search() || is_front_page() ) : ?>

I do this and again is full text on front page, what i need to do ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: i fixed all this problem with this plugin,

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-custom-auto-excerpt/