# Excerpt content

Tags: excerpt

I want to display the title with content in result in search engine using excerpt. I see an answer for excerpt, [See this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt/141136#141136), but I'm confuse where do I place this code... in function or wp-includes/formatting.php?

```
function wpse_allowedtags() {
// Add custom tags to this string
    return '<script>,<style>,<br>,<em>,<i>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<a>,<p>,<img>,<video>, <audio>'; 
}

 if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) ) : 

function wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($wpse_excerpt) {
global $post;
$raw_excerpt = $wpse_excerpt;
    if ( '' == $wpse_excerpt ) {

        $wpse_excerpt = get_the_content('');
        $wpse_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $wpse_excerpt );
        $wpse_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $wpse_excerpt);
        $wpse_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $wpse_excerpt);
        $wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags()); /*IF you need to  allow just certain tags. Delete if all tags are allowed */

        //Set the excerpt word count and only break after sentence is complete.
            $excerpt_word_count = 75;
            $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
            $tokens = array();
            $excerptOutput = '';
            $count = 0;

            // Divide the string into tokens; HTML tags, or words, followed by any whitespace
            preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>|[^<>\s]+)\s*/u', $wpse_excerpt, $tokens);

            foreach ($tokens[0] as $token) { 

                if ($count >= $excerpt_word_count && preg_match('/[\,\;\?\.\!]\s*$/uS', $token)) { 
                // Limit reached, continue until , ; ? . or ! occur at the end
                    $excerptOutput .= trim($token);
                    break;
                }

                // Add words to complete sentence
                $count++;

                // Append what's left of the token
                $excerptOutput .= $token;
            }

        $wpse_excerpt = trim(force_balance_tags($excerptOutput));

            $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' .   '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'wpse' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
            $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

            //$pos = strrpos($wpse_excerpt, '</');
            //if ($pos !== false)
            // Inside last HTML tag
            //$wpse_excerpt = substr_replace($wpse_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0); /*    Add read more next to last word */
            //else
            // After the content
            $wpse_excerpt .= $excerpt_end; /*Add read more in new paragraph */

        return $wpse_excerpt;   

    }
    return apply_filters('wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $wpse_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
}

endif; 

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

Comment: You do not add anything in WordPress core files which includes files in wp-admin and wp-includes. All custom functions must go in current theme's functions.php

Comment: ...or into a plugin (even better).

Comment: I have edited my post to explain where the code should go. Please see the prephase in the linked answer. :-)