# Why aren't paragraphs breaking on this page?

Tags: posts, shortcode, recent-posts

[This page](http://www.winnebagoparts.com/specials/top-100-products/) is created using a recent posts shortcode included with my theme. It is not displaying paragraph breaks that I've added in the editor and I'd like it to. How can I get the shortcode to display the paragraph breaks?

This is the code that compiles the list of recent posts:

```
if (!function_exists('mo_get_thumbnail_post_list')) {
function mo_get_thumbnail_post_list($args) {

    /* Set the default arguments. */
    $defaults = array(
        'loop' => null,
        'image_size' => 'small',
        'style' => null,
        'show_meta' => false,
        'excerpt_count' => 120,
        'hide_thumbnail' => false
    );

    /* Merge the input arguments and the defaults. */
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);

    /* Extract the array to allow easy use of variables. */
    extract($args);

    if ($loop->have_posts()):

        $css_class = $image_size . '-size';

        $image_size = mo_get_post_image_size($image_size);

        $style = ($style ? ' ' . $style : '');

        $output = '<ul class="post-list' . $style . ' ' . $css_class . '">';

        $hide_thumbnail = mo_to_boolean($hide_thumbnail);

        $show_meta = mo_to_boolean($show_meta);

        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

            $output .= '<li>';

            $thumbnail_exists = false;

            $output .= "\n" . '<div class="' . join(' ', get_post_class()) . '">' . "\n"; // Removed id="post-'.get_the_ID() to help avoid duplicate IDs validation error in the page

            if (!$hide_thumbnail) {
                $thumbnail_url = mo_get_thumbnail(array('image_size' => $image_size));
                if (!empty($thumbnail_url)) {
                    $thumbnail_exists = true;
                    $output .= $thumbnail_url;
                }
            }

            $output .= "\n" . '<div class="entry-text-wrap ' . ($thumbnail_exists ? '' : 'nothumbnail') . '">';

            $output .= "\n" . the_title('<div class="entry-title"><h2><a title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2></div>', false);

            if ($show_meta) {
                $output .= '<div class="byline">' . mo_entry_published() . mo_entry_comments_number() . '</div>';
            }

            if ($excerpt_count != 0) {

                $output .= "\n" . '<div class="entry-summary">';

                $output .= get_the_content();

                $output .= "\n" . '</div><!-- entry-summary -->';
            }

            $output .= "\n" . '</div><!-- entry-text-wrap -->';

            $output .= "\n" . '</div><!-- .hentry -->';

            $output .= '</li>';

        endwhile;

        $output .= '</ul>';

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $output;
}
}
```

I've contacted the theme creator about this and they haven't been too helpful with the matter.

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141136/31545)

Comment: you will need to ask the plugin's author.

Comment: The theme author has not been too helpful.

Comment: [see `get_the_content()` in codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) for an example which applies `the_content` filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_content()` returns unfiltered content, and using a shortcode you cannot use `the_content()` to return filtered content as you cannot echo inside a shortcode. Your best option here will be is to applying `the_content` filters to `get_the_content()`, something like:

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
```

### EDIT

Exact usage, replace

```
$output .= get_the_content();
```

with

```
$output .= apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
```

Comment: it's safer to use `get_the_content()` in place of `$post->post_content`.

Comment: Ya sorry, I'm being stupid again here. Posted before I even thought this trough. Just ignore that, will update my answer. Thanks

Comment: This returned a blank output on my site. This solution seems to work: http://www.web-templates.nu/2008/08/31/get_the_content-with-formatting/

Comment: Strange, works for me. Depend how you've used it. Will post exact usage

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thank you for clarifying how to use it properly—I had added it to the functions.php file and not directly to the shortcode function.

Comment: No problem :-). Remember to accept your own answer as the correct one by clicking on the checkmark next to it after the two day restraint is lifted. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](http://www.web-templates.nu/2008/08/31/get_the_content-with-formatting/):

```
function get_the_content_with_formatting ($more_link_text = '(more...)', $stripteaser = 0, $more_file = '') {
$content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
return $content;
}
```