# Display inner pages like posts.[Like how post excerpt works]

Tags: pages, child-pages, excerpt

This question may be stupid. But, i'm just wondering if there is a possibly way to display page as excerpt like how post excerpt works. You may not be able to understand what am i trying to ask till now.

Well! I try to point out the main subject of this question with examples. The question is actually very simple. For example: We have a main page for displaying all the posts and the way all the posts showing as an excerpt(we need to click to read the full post). Is there a way for page as well? When i am in the page(about) which has a few more child pages(company vision, company services, company news and etc), under that page named "About".

Hopefully this question won't get down-voting.

Comment: Hi Pieter Goosen, i've read your earlier comment. Yes! English is not my primary language. Yes! That was what i mean. I want to have the excerpt link to click to single page.

Comment: Have a look at my post about excerpts [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141136/31545)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the page post type does not show the excerpt box like posts, but you can enable it like this(code goes into your theme's functions.php file):

```
add_action('init', 'excerpt_for_pages');
function excerpt_for_pages() {
    add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

Then you can see the excerpt field when you edit your page. If not, make sure it is turned on. Click Screen Options in the top right corner and make sure Excerpt is checked.

Comment: Thanks Passatgt! I'm trying it out. Do i need to implement any different php code in order to make all the inner pages displaying in one main page as excerpt?