# Replace comments with a dummy text

Tags: comments

I want to hide comments for a certain time and show a sample text in the comment text area.
Say, there are 50 comments on a post. What I want is- hide every comments on this post and there will be a text saying "this comment is hidden". Is it possible?

I am very new with WordPress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, possible.

Add this to your theme's `functions.php` file-

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_text', 'replace_comment_texts' );

function replace_comment_texts() {
    return "This comment is hidden";
}
```

I have written a plugin few days back, that does the exact thing. You can try this too- https://wordpress.org/plugins/mask-comments/

Comment: but what if I change the theme? should I replace replace this functions.php file?

Comment: Anyway, that plugin works.

Comment: @pranesh, create an [`mu-plugins`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt) folder in `wp-content`, create in that folder a *.php file and add there your code which you want to be used for whatever `theme`.  OR create your own [`plugin`](https://codex.wordpress.org./Writing_a_Plugin) with that kind of code snippets.