# Display only text to WordPress loop without loosing the text formatting

Tags: php, loop, filters, text

I want to display text from content (only text) with the formating (paragraph, bold, italic.) on loop.
When I am using this code:

```
<?php echo mb_substr( strip_tags( get_the_excerpt() ),0,255); ?>
```

or

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

The text displayed without the text formating. No p, br even the hr is disappear.

When I am using this code:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',substr(get_the_content(),0,550)); ?>
```

The text displayed with the format, but the other content also display (image, video and else)  I just want to display the text with the format.

Anybody know how to resolve the problem?
Really appreciate for any help

Thank you

Comment: I think (*could be wrong*) you will find [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt) your answer.

Comment: @charles : thank you. It's look like similar to what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your theme's `functions.php` file-

```
function filtered_content($content){
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content); // removes images
    $content = preg_replace('/<iframe.*?>/', "", $content); // removes iframes
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filtered_content');
```

This will remove img and iframe tag from your content. Then use `the_content()` in your template.

Comment: thank you. I tried and work fine. But unfortunately, affect to other look which use the_content(). Will check then.