# custom wordpress post loop - hide iframe content

Tags: posts, loop

I am trying to create a custom loop to display my posts in different styling.

In my posts, I have mostly Youtube videos and some text around. In my posts loop I need to display only thumbnail of the featured image of the posts and the text, but I don't want to display any iframes with my Youtube videos.

I was searching for solutions nad I found this - [Display only text to WordPress loop without loosing the text formatting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218305/display-only-text-to-wordpress-loop-without-loosing-the-text-formatting/218314#218314) - it should remove iframes and images, which would be great for me, but I have multiple posts loop so I don't really want to affect `the_content()` function because it is used in many more different loops in my theme, if you understand my problem. I am not really a programmer so this is tough for me.

**edit 1** 
I have added your code into functions.php but nothing happens. here's my code in template:

```
<?php 
    global $post; 
    $args = array('orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => 1,); 

    $custom_posts = get_posts($args); foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <div class="hpvybirame">
    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

    <?php show_only_thumbnails($content); ?>
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'vlog-lay-c'); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: How are you embedding the youtube videos? Are you using the embed shortcode or putting the iframes in your content?

Comment: I just add the "link" into wordpress post editor and in a second wordpress loads video by itself. You can see it live here: http://veckotest.8u.cz/ - under the main big video there's random displayed video and two text blocks on the right side ... If I click with right button on the mouse on the displayed video and open the firebug, I can see in the code "iframe" ... but when I display the code of the page, then I don't see this block with video and text content at all ... now I am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution is to add filter in your functions.php  :

```
add_filter('the_content','show_only_thumbnails',99);

function show_only_thumbnails($content){
    if(is_home() && is_front_page()){
     //quote from :
     //http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218305/display-only-text-to-wordpress-loop-without-loosing-the-text-formatting/218314#218314
     $content = preg_replace('/<iframe.*?>/', "", $content); // removes iframes
      return $content;
    }
   return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can understand what this code does, it looks good, but I didn't mention that this my loop is displayed on page, where are more post loops, if you understand what I mean, so I guess that even other loops which also use "the_content" will be affected by this filther? right? If that's true then this is not the best solution for my situation ... sorry for mentioning this in second comment, I should have mention this information above...

Comment: I guess I need some code (function?) to do exactly the same thing as the_content() but with this preg_replace special line of code from this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218305/display-only-text-to-wordpress-loop-without-loosing-the-text-formatting/218314#218314 - but I don't really want to affect the_content() function because it is used on the same page in other loops too

Comment: you can try using add_post_meta to the post to reference the tags or iframes  or thumbnails and in functions.php you can decide whether to show or hide or replace , if this is not helping try posting a full snippet of the code

Comment: I am trying to display "random post" on homepage with it's own loop. All my posts contain one paragraph of text and one youtube video. In my loop on homepage I want to display the paragraph of text - so I am using the_content() to do that but it also displays the youtube video. I want to hide the youtube video so I need to "filter out" the iframe code. I have also other loops on my homepage that use "the_content()" and showing the youtube video and I want to keep it that way, so I think that I need to create maybe the_content2() function that filters out iframe - It would work perfectly for me

Comment: But I am not a programmer and I don't reall know how to write this in code :-/

Comment: try the above code i think it will work for you

Comment: I'Ve tryed your solutions, but nothing happesn, I've added above the code in my templeate file

Comment: it should be added to functions.php and the preg_replace should replace the iframe

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to achieve this using the [**is_main_query**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) function and the_content filter.

The **`is_main_query`** checks if the current query is the main or secondary query in the loop.

```
function wpse253491_strip( $content ) {
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() && !is_main_query() ) {
        $content = preg_replace('#<\s*iframe[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*iframe>#msi', '', $content);
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpdocs_remove_shortcode_from_index' );
```