# HTML tags not showing in excerpt

Tags: php, excerpt

I have implemented the following excellent example by Pieter Goosen:

[Allow HTML in excerpt](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt)

However, the HTML tags in my excerpt are getting stripped out anyways. If I throw in a `echo $raw_excerpt` right at the top of the custom function, I get my excerpt with the HTML already stripped out.

Is this a priority issue? Seems the default `wp_trim_excerpt` filter is running before the custom filter even though I remove it as in the example.

Anyone have a clue for me here?

EDIT: code included. Nothing special. Copied verbatim from the example and placed in functions.php file in theme.

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) ) : 

    function wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($wpse_excerpt) {
    $raw_excerpt = $wpse_excerpt;
    echo $raw_excerpt;
        if ( '' == $wpse_excerpt ) {

            $wpse_excerpt = get_the_content('');
            $wpse_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $wpse_excerpt );
            $wpse_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $wpse_excerpt);
            $wpse_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $wpse_excerpt);
            //$wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags()); /*IF you need to allow just certain tags. Delete if all tags are allowed */

            //Set the excerpt word count and only break after sentence is complete.
                $excerpt_word_count = 75;
                $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
                $tokens = array();
                $excerptOutput = '';
                $count = 0;

                // Divide the string into tokens; HTML tags, or words, followed by any whitespace
                preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>|[^<>\s]+)\s*/u', $wpse_excerpt, $tokens);

                foreach ($tokens[0] as $token) { 

                    if ($count >= $excerpt_length && preg_match('/[\,\;\?\.\!]\s*$/uS', $token)) { 
                    // Limit reached, continue until , ; ? . or ! occur at the end
                        $excerptOutput .= trim($token);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Add words to complete sentence
                    $count++;

                    // Append what's left of the token
                    $excerptOutput .= $token;
                }

            $wpse_excerpt = trim(force_balance_tags($excerptOutput));

                $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'wpse' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
                $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

                //$pos = strrpos($wpse_excerpt, '</');
                //if ($pos !== false)
                // Inside last HTML tag
                //$wpse_excerpt = substr_replace($wpse_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0); /* Add read more next to last word */
                //else
                // After the content
                $wpse_excerpt .= $excerpt_more; /*Add read more in new paragraph */

            return $wpse_excerpt;   

        }
        return apply_filters('wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $wpse_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
    }

endif; 

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');


<div class="slideshow-dfmi-title">Welcome</div>
<div class="slideshow-dfmi-body">Some Text</div>
```

**EDIT 9/26:** I added a priority of 1 to the add_filter statement above and my echo $raw_excerpt call dumped out my excerpt with all html intact. So, it would seem that the remove_filter statement is NOT removing the wp_trim_excerpt filter. Hmmm.

Comment: May you provide your code as well as the HTML that you're trying ot run in your excerpt?

Comment: @Ethan Jinks O'Sullivan - there you go.