# What's the best way to trim content from WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: editor, formatting, wysiwyg

I have done an excessive amount of googling and haven't found exactly what I need yet.

The client uses the editor (WYSIWYG) to create posts. She adds photos, links to external photos, videos, embeds external videos, and all other formatting. But she does **not** use the  tag **nor** the excerpt field.

When I use `wp_trim_words()` I get mixed results.

- Posts with local videos leak markup onto the page
- A couple posts are only images so there isn't any content at all
- Posts with a lot of formatting look really wonky

Anyone have any other ideas on how to trim content or better ways to use wp_trim_words() ?

EDIT: To make myself clear basically what I want is a trimmed version of the full post that still contains all the formatting, images, videos, links, embeds, whatever else she throws into the editor. I do not want markup leaking through, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

wp_strip_all_tags() will strip out all the tags.

However with posts which just have images and no content. There is no solution to that, the excerpt or wherever you are trying to use it will show blank since it cannot "magically" create content for the post when there is no content at all.

For more info > https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_strip_all_tags

Comment: sorry, I didn't make myself clear, I do not want to strip tags. I essentially just want a shorter exact version of the full post but down to size. Formatting, images, videos, links, whatever remain intact

Comment: then use the_excerpt()

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/

Comment: Am I missing somethign? By default the_excerpt() isn't displaying formatting, images, video, links, etc. just a single paragraph

Comment: Oh well, then you might consider looking at this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt#answer-141136