# Include image in excerpt

Tags: images, excerpt

I'm using WP Rest API to retrieve post information to display on another system. One of the things I'm retrieving is the excerpts of the posts.

I'd like to include images in the excerpt retrieved. How would you suggest this is done? I'm assuming Wordpress strips out elements within tags such as `<img>`. Could it be done by preventing Wordpress from removing  tags? Or is there a faster way? Or maybe an existing plugin?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It does trim HTML tags, but Peter Goosen posted a method to allow tags in the excerpt. Try this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141136/33393