# the_excerpt displaying code inside style tag

Tags: shortcode, search, tags, excerpt, css

I created a custom visual composer element where I included a style tag on it to use the chosen color to create hover effect.
And this code is now displaying in the the_excerpt in the search result page when one of the results is a page and has the custom element on it.
https://www.beproductive.ie/?s=learn

See the privacy policy on for example.

Is there a way to make the_excerpt ignorer the  tag?

Answer (score 0):

the_excerpt strips away html tags.  You will need to switch to the_content and use  quick tag instead.

view the [**docs on this**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)

Basic Example:

```
<?php the_content( 'Read more ...' ); ?>
```

Comment: But if I use the_content its display the page banners, images and icons.

Comment: It is possible to re-write the_excerpt, see [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt/141136).  Another option might be to switch to the_content but use CSS to hide any images, banners, etc you don't want to show on your listing page.