# HTML in excerpt Wordpress 6.2.2

Tags: excerpt

A while back (5+ years) I was asked to build a site where there was some HTML needed in the WP excerpt, from what I can remember I achived this by overriding "get_the_excerpt" something like the accepted answer here: [Allow HTML in excerpt](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt)

This does not seem to work in the latest version of WP 6.2.2 (at time of writing), can someone point me in the right direction for allowing a few HTML tags to be included in the excerpt?

If I alter formatting.php > strip_all_tags as below, this gets me the result I am looking for, but obviously altering the core is not a solution, how would I achive the same thing in my child themes functions.php

```
function wp_strip_all_tags( $text, $remove_breaks = false ) {
    if ( is_null( $text ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( ! is_scalar( $text ) ) {
        /*
         * To maintain consistency with pre-PHP 8 error levels,
         * trigger_error() is used to trigger an E_USER_WARNING,
         * rather than _doing_it_wrong(), which triggers an E_USER_NOTICE.
         */
        trigger_error(
            sprintf(
                /* translators: 1: The function name, 2: The argument number, 3: The argument name, 4: The expected type, 5: The provided type. */
                __( 'Warning: %1$s expects parameter %2$s (%3$s) to be a %4$s, %5$s given.' ),
                __FUNCTION__,
                '#1',
                '$text',
                'string',
                gettype( $text )
            ),
            E_USER_WARNING
        );

        return '';
    }

    $text = preg_replace( '@<(script|style)[^>]*?>.*?</\\1>@si', '', $text );
    $text = strip_tags( $text, '<h3>, <div>, <span>' ); // TO DO OVERRIDE

    if ( $remove_breaks ) {
        $text = preg_replace( '/[\r\n\t ]+/', ' ', $text );
    }

    return trim( $text );
}
```

Comment: Are you using one of the default themes? Need to rule out the theme doing any extra work.

Comment: In my testing, it seems that manual excerpts permit HTML, but auto-generated excerpts strip tags.

Comment: We are using the Divi theme, and the posts are being created by gravity forms, I did contact gravity and they suggested they don’t do anything out of the ordinary the posts are just WP posts according to them.

Answer (score 0):

To get started, you'll need to remove [the `wp_trim_excerpt` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_excerpt/) from the `get_the_excerpt` filter:

```php
remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt', 10 );
```

This will result in no auto-generation of excerpts (manually entered excerpts will still show).

From here, add your own function and filter for generating the excerpt:

```php
function trim_excerpt_with_html( $text = '', $post = null ) {
    ...
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'trim_excerpt_with_html', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks Caleb, I will give this a go.